# CSS transform not working correctly with position sticky

Tags: html, css

When using transform property with sticky headers, the transformed element shows on top of the header.

Here is a fiddle to show the problem

https://jsfiddle.net/v7h4dkLn/

```
<html>
<style>
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.long-content {
  height: 600px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.the-problem {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="long-content">
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <span class="the-problem">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice when scrolling down, the rotated 'X' shows on top of the header. If you remove the transform the 'X' goes under the header which is the expected behaviour.

Any knows why is behaving like this? And how to resolve it while maintaining the rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you're trying to achieve.

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  
  .header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  
  .long-content {
    height: 600px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .the-problem {
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="long-content">
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <span class="the-problem">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is add a z-index to the header. your example should be working, it's just the layering order of the elements.

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
  z-index: 100;
}

.long-content {
  height: 600px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.the-problem {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="long-content">
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <span class="the-problem">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask why it behaves this way when a transform is added.

The transform creates a new stacking context, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Give the header a z-index (1 is enough in your example) to bring it above.

```
.header {
  z-index: 1;
}
```